# Display tooltip through invisible control /button WPF

Tags: wpf

Why is tooltip not displaying when hovering item behind transparent control in WPF? 
How can i make the UserControl display the tooltip through the invisible control? I also tried with a rectangle instead of button, same result, no tooltip.

```
<Grid Height="100" Width="100">
    <Rectangle Fill="Red"   ToolTip="Tooltip is behind button" Height="20" Width="20" Margin="7,40,73,40"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="Yellow"   ToolTip="Also behind" Height="20" Width="20" Margin="67,40,13,40"/>
    <Button Opacity="0" Background="Transparent"  Height="100" Width="100"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `IsHitTestVisible="False"` for the `Button` .

EDIT #1 after user comments.

I think you should do this :

```
 <Button BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="Transparent"  Height="100" Width="100">
    <Grid Height="100" Width="100">
        <Rectangle Fill="Red"   ToolTip="Tooltip is behind button" Height="20" Width="20" Margin="7,40,73,40"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Yellow"   ToolTip="Also behind" Height="20" Width="20" Margin="67,40,13,40"/>
    </Grid>
 </Button>
```

Comment: The button does not seem to respond on clicks now?

Comment: @Snovva1 then u cannot achieve what your trying to do with tooltips.

Comment: I think this solves the case for me. I'll test it and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Set Panel ZIndex in order to bring your element to the front:

```
<Grid Height="100" Width="100">
        <Rectangle Panel.ZIndex="2" Fill="Red" ToolTip="Tooltip is behind button" Height="20" Width="20" Margin="7,40,73,40"/>
        <Rectangle Panel.ZIndex="1" Fill="Yellow"   ToolTip="Also behind" Height="20" Width="20" Margin="67,40,13,40"/>
        <Button Panel.ZIndex="0" Opacity="0" Background="Transparent"  Height="100" Width="100"/>
    </Grid>
```